# I got value of user meta key like a:1:{s:8:"investor";b:1;}

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have got like this meta key `a:1:{s:8:"investor";b:1;}`  but i want get only one string like `"investor"` in switch case condition.

Comment: this is a serialized array. `a:1` -> there is one array key.. `s:8` -> it is a string containing 8 chars.. `investor` -> your array index

Comment: if you run `$yourNewArray = unserialize($yourMetaVar)` it becomes an array again. - then you can use `$yourNewArray[0]` as your value.

Comment: or.. close to that... just tur it into an array again, and you will figure it out

Comment: `b:1` is probably your boolean value for investor key

Comment: so `$yourNewArray[0]` returns the `b`

Comment: @Stender I got NULL value

Comment: what do you get, if you just `var_dump(unserialize($yourMetaVar));` ?

Comment: I have created a playground for you here, so you can fiddle with my idea https://www.tehplayground.com/5eZWwkjp49e9zFxb

Comment: updated here : https://www.tehplayground.com/nEJ04qJC7pdjNK50 - ctrl+enter to run scripts

Comment: https://www.tehplayground.com/FRH4Rwyuut6CBOIl here i mention my code plz check and let me know how to impliment my code @Stender

Comment: @Stender thank you very much its work fine i got string